# Determine general form of solution for $y'=e^y \cos(x)$ and maximum solution interval.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this differential equation:

$$y'=e^y \cos(x)$$

Is there any method for this because if it would be in case of $e^y$ it is simple to solve but in such situation I don't have any idea.

Comment: The equation is separable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = e^y \cos x
$$
$$
e^{-y}\,dy = \cos x\, dx
$$
$$
\int e^{-y}\,dy = \int \cos x\,dx
$$
$$
\text{etc.}
$$